# Custom Attributes and Schema in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps

Is it possible to create custom attributes in Google apps, like adding mobile number for each user, etc. Is there any method to get the schema of the google apps entity using API

Answer (score 0):

You can store contact information in the [directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) you can also create an entry for each user as shared contacts which can have richer information, including extended properties for adding custom key value pairs, the schema is the same as a [contact entry](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements#gdContactKind)

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced [changes to the Directory API](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/09/new-features-in-admin-sdk-custom-user.html) that allow you to add custom attributes to user profiles.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas